# aws-sdk-php + zend framework 2 skeleton => signal Segmentation fault (11)

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zend-framework2

I'm trying to use AWS S3 in my recent project built on Zend Framework 2.

Something really strange happened and I have not been able to find the solution.

I started a fresh Zend Framework 2 Skeleton application and installed [aws/aws-sdk-php](http://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) via composer.

A simple S3::putObject request was created:

```
$client = S3Client::factory(array(
        'key' => 'xxx',
        'secret' => 'xxx',
        'region' => 'xxx',
    ));

$client->putObject(array(
                'Bucket' => $bucket,
                'Key' => '/test/test.html',
                'Body' => 'This is a test' . time(),
                'ContentType' => 'text/html',
                'Acl' => CannedAcl::PUBLIC_READ
            ));
```

The above code works fine when I test it in PHPUnit. However when I open the browser to see result from same IndexController, Firefox just reported 'The connection was reset'. PHP doesn't throw any exceptions

I opened Apache's error log and see:

```
[Tue Jul 08 04:58:58 2014] [notice] child pid 33428 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jul 08 04:59:15 2014] [notice] child pid 33439 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jul 08 04:59:16 2014] [notice] child pid 33361 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jul 08 05:02:02 2014] [notice] child pid 33452 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jul 08 05:02:50 2014] [notice] child pid 33142 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jul 08 05:04:34 2014] [notice] child pid 33317 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jul 08 05:04:35 2014] [notice] child pid 33143 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jul 08 05:06:18 2014] [notice] child pid 33522 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jul 08 05:06:19 2014] [notice] child pid 33534 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I googled the error and found different answers to this problem but none seems to apply to me.

After trying the latest Zend Server 7 I managed to nail down the problem in [Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle3/blob/master/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php), seems that something happened during curl_multi_* operations. I think the problem should be PHP is in infinite loop, but how come it works fine under PHPUnit? It has nothing to do with running from CLI because I just tried curl the same URL and got:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

So it looks like the problem still come from inside the code...

Some posts from Google stating this curl problem might because of OSX Maverick's openssl issue but I don't think I have this problem since my curl works fine with any https requests.

And my research on this problem stops here :(

aws-sdk-php has been out for quite a long while I don't believe it is the lib's fault, can it be my machine? Here is my software environment

```
OSX Mavericks 10.9.4
Zend Server 7 with PHP 5.5.13
curl --version
curl 7.30.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0) libcurl/7.30.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

Comment: I had the same problem on AWS linux server.

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours tracking down the same problem, it happens when openssl support is not built into the version of libcurl used to build the curl extension:

**build.log**

```
checking for openssl support in libcurl... no
```

You'll need to install curl with openssl support, e.g. using brew: `brew install curl --with-openssl` (`--with-openssl` may not be required).

Once an openssl supported libcurl is available, you'll need to add the option `--with-curl` to your build command, for me this was `phpbrew .. --with-curl=/usr/local/opt/curl`.